# php-excel-reader - problem with UTF-8

Tags: php, excel, unicode

I'm using [php-excel-reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/) 2.21 for converting XLS file to CSV. I wrote a simple script to do that, but I have some problems with unicode characters. It does not return values from some cells.

For example it doesn't have problems with cell content `ceník položek` but have problems with `nákup`, `VÝROBCE`, `PÁS`, `HRUBÝ`,`NÁKLADNÍ` and some others. In these cells it returns empty value (`""`).

Here is the code snippet I use for conversion:

```
<?php    
set_time_limit(120);    
require_once 'excel_reader2.php';    
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("cenik.xls", false, 'UTF-8');    

$f = fopen('file.csv', 'w');    
for($row = 1; $row <= $data->rowcount(); $row++)    
{    
    $out = '';    
    for($col = 1; $col <= $data->colcount(); $col++)    
    {    
        $val = $data->val($row,$col);

        // escape " and \ characters inside the cell    
        $escaped = preg_replace(array('#”#u', '#\\\\#u', '#[”"]#u'), array('"', '\\\\\\\\', '\"'), $val);    
        if(empty($val))    
            $out .= ',';    
        else    
            $out .= '"' . $escaped . '",';    
    }
    // remove last comma (,)    
    fwrite($f, substr($out, 0, -1));    
    fwrite($f, "\n");
}
fclose($f);

?>
```

Note that the cell and row indexes starts from 1. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can anybody tell that Which answer is more applicable or more proper way? Mr. cypher's Or @thuclh which answer is ideal?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I hope it's the same problem as I had:
In excel_reader2.php on line 1120, replace

```
$retstr = ($asciiEncoding) ? $retstr : $this->_encodeUTF16($retstr);
```

with

```
$retstr = ($asciiEncoding) ? iconv('cp1250', 'utf-8', $retstr) : $this->_encodeUTF16($retstr);
```

That should fix it, however I suggest you use a different excel reader, such as [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) to avoid problems like these.
Note that you need `iconv` extension enabled on the server.

Comment: (This is a different question and should be posted separately.)

Comment: Worked. But had to replace 'cp1250' for 'iso-8859-1''.

Comment: Which value should I replace 'cp1250' if I want to read Chinese character?   I had tried 'cp950', 'iso-8859-1' as @AndréMorales suggestion but still no luck.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect.

Comment: Thanks. Works fine!

Answer (score 10):

I has the answer for this problem, use php_excel_reader like common!
Add a function to Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader class:

```
function seems_utf8($str) {
        for ($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++) {
            if (ord($str[$i]) < 0x80) continue; # 0bbbbbbb
            elseif ((ord($str[$i]) & 0xE0) == 0xC0) $n=1; # 110bbbbb
            elseif ((ord($str[$i]) & 0xF0) == 0xE0) $n=2; # 1110bbbb
            elseif ((ord($str[$i]) & 0xF8) == 0xF0) $n=3; # 11110bbb
            elseif ((ord($str[$i]) & 0xFC) == 0xF8) $n=4; # 111110bb
            elseif ((ord($str[$i]) & 0xFE) == 0xFC) $n=5; # 1111110b
            else return false; # Does not match any model
            for ($j=0; $j<$n; $j++) { # n bytes matching 10bbbbbb follow ?
                if ((++$i == strlen($str)) || ((ord($str[$i]) & 0xC0) != 0x80))
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And add below line 1120: `$retstr = $this->seems_utf8($retstr)?$retstr:utf8_encode($retstr);`

### Finish!

You can use file php_excel_reader, that i modify!
Download here :  [File excel_reader2.php](http://www.mediafire.com/?yzeexdb3ztfb1we)
Use like common with [Original-excel-reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/)

Comment: You are a champ! Thanks for this. The solution provided above is buggy. It converts è to č, I guess the incoming encoding may not be 'cp1250'. Mine is already utf-8

Comment: utf8_encode() accepts string in ISO-8859-1 and converts it to utf8. But how can you guarantee that $retstr will always be either in ISO-8859-1 or UTF8?

Comment: I had tried but it does not work with Chinese character :(