# Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader (PHPExcelReader) fails on accent encoding

Tags: php, excel

I'm using [Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/) for reading Excel file in my PHP app. It works fine until I put some accents in my Excel file, they are not correctly handled : "éçà@" for example. I've seen that encoding can be set through :

```
$reader->setOutputEncoding($encoding);
```

But this doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php-excel-reader - problem with UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666412/php-excel-reader-problem-with-utf-8)

Answer (score 2):

Line 562

```
 $retstr = ($asciiEncoding) ? $retstr : $this->_encodeUTF16($retstr);
```

edit this way

```
 $retstr = ($asciiEncoding) ? utf8_encode($retstr) : $this->_encodeUTF16($retstr);
```

Comment: Grazie, I'm no more on this project so I can't check right now.

Answer (score -3):

I used

```
$data->setOutputEncoding('UTF8');
```

and it is working fine for me.

Comment: I ended up by replacing manually wrong caracters... This didn't worked on my spreadsheet.