# php Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader data contain unwanted � when insert into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, excel

When read a Excel file using `Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader data` contain unwanted � between each characters,When insert it into mysql DB. How to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a character set mismatch.  This question on SO might help re. the spreadsheet: [php-excel-reader - problem with UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666412/php-excel-reader-problem-with-utf-8) and then check that your tables/columns are using the same (ideally UTF-8) character set, and that your connection is also using UTF-8.