# Import date from excel file to database using php

Tags: php, sql, database, excel

Please there're an esay way to Import date from excel file to database using php ?

I have made it by excel_reader2

but the last char don't load and I get problem with arabic language

This is my code

```
    <?php
require_once 'excel_reader2.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($url);
$page_sheet = 1;
if(count($data->sheets[$page_sheet][cells])>0) // checking sheet not empty
{

    $rows = count($data->sheets[$page_sheet][cells]);

    for($j=5;$j<=count($data->sheets[$page_sheet][cells]);$j++) // loop used to get each row of the sheet
    {
        $data->sheets[$page_sheet][cells][$j][1];
        $rowid = $data->sheets[$page_sheet][cells][$j][1];
        $phone = $data->sheets[$page_sheet][cells][$j][2];
        $season = $data->sheets[$page_sheet][cells][$j][3];
        $row = $data->sheets[$page_sheet][cells][$j][4];
        $name = $data->sheets[$page_sheet][cells][$j][5];

       echo "$name<br />";
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad english please

Comment: Do you get the last character if you add one to the count? `for($j=5;$j<=count($data->sheets[$page_sheet][cells])+1;$j++)`

Comment: This answer might help with displaying Arabic characters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666412/php-excel-reader-problem-with-utf-8 which says:"To use a coding other than UTF-8 (default) you can pass it as the 3rd parameter.
`$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("test.xls",true,"UTF-16");`"

Comment: If you echo any of the other items are they all blank? Can you add any more information about what you do get out and what you expect to see?

Comment: This script seems to echo everything so at least you could see what you are getting. It also seems to cope with multiple sheets in a workbook http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-read-excel-file-insert-data-into-mysql-database-using-php_609.html  This line without any `$variable =` might be a problem  `$data->sheets[$page_sheet][cells][$j][1];` at the top of your variables block - comment it out.

Comment: Have you tried `$page_sheet = 0;` ?  Also this was recommended on the other page an looks to have better language handling PHPExcel: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/  also on https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: Hi guys thank you so much ... I have solved the problem ... I just need to save the file before Import

Comment: Glad to hear that. Good luck with it, hope the links will be useful.